# Best way to capture errors from custom spl_autloader functions

Tags: php, model-view-controller, exception, include, autoload

To gain a deeper understanding of the MVC paradigm, I'm experimenting with building my own framework.

Rather than rely on PHP's ugly error/warning that results from a failed include, I set up a general exception class that presents the data in a more human readable format, along with a stacktrace.

Here's the code I have so far...

```
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__.'\Autoloader::coreLoader');
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__.'\Autoloader::appLoader');
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__.'\Autoloader::throwException');

class Autoloader
{
    private static $isError = false;

    private static function loadHelper($className)
    {
        //Relevant code here
    }

    public static function coreLoader($className)
    {
        $classPath = static::loadHelper($className);

        if (!@include PRIVATE_ROOT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$classPath.PHPEXT)
        {
            static::$isError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            static::$isError = false;
        }
    }

    public static function appLoader($className)
    {
        $classPath = static::loadHelper($className);

        if (!@include SYSTEM_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$classPath.PHPEXT)
        {
            static::$isError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            static::$isError = false;
        }
    }

    public static function throwException($className)
    {
        if (static::$isError)
        {
            throw new Exception_General('Attempted to load file: '.$className);
        }
    }
}
```

Given the fact that `include` does not generate an exception when a file is not found, I cannot use a try/catch block.

In place of the try/catch block, I've found that one can use an `if statement` as in the code above to check if the `include` statement was successful in loading the required file.

My `Exception_General` class is responsible for generating and displaying developer friendly error output/messages. The problem that I face here though is that if I throw an Exception within a legitimate autoloading method, the script will rightfully halt.

This of course is not ideal as while the first autoloading method might not find the requested class, the 2nd or 3rd autoloading method in the spl_autoload queue MIGHT be able to find the requested file/class.

In order to accommodate this behaviour, I find that I've had to create a 3rd "fake" autoloading method that is the last to be called in the queue -- this method checks the error flag, and if set, throws the exception.

In a bit of a long winded question, what I'm really asking is -- Is there a better way to capture failed includes and once all the autoloading functions have run their course, act appropriately?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I don't necessarily think this is a great solution, particularly as some callbacks will be duplicated, but I'll put it up as a potential source of inspiration.*

I've just had a fiddle with this and come up with an autoload method that, if it is used in an autoload attempt, will throw an exception at the end of the sequence if the class is not found.  It does this by modifying the autoload stack whilst the autoloading procedure is taking place, and calling autoloading recursively.  The benefit of all this wizardry is that the exception will only be thrown if all callbacks fail, and it doesn't require a dummy callback, which would interfere with later registered callbacks.

```
function a() { echo "a\n"; }
function b() { echo "b\n"; }

class Autoloader {
  // This prevents infinite recursion.
  static $loading = false;

  // This is the callback for this autoloader, for convenience.
  static $callback = ['Autoloader', 'autoload'];

  static function autoload($class_name) {
    if(!static::$loading) {
      // Basically what we do here is repeat the autoload cycle, and if it fails
      // throw an exception.
      $autoloaders = spl_autoload_functions(); // All registered autoloaders.
      $priority = array_search(static::$callback, $autoloaders);
      $past = []; // An array for callbacks that have already occurred.
      for($i = 0; $i < $priority; $i++) {
        $past[] = $autoloaders[$i]; // Fill the past events
        spl_autoload_unregister($autoloaders[$i]); // Remove it from the stack
      }
      // We have now taken off the callbacks that ran before this one

      static::$loading = true; // Make sure we don't get stuck.
      spl_autoload_call($class_name); // 'Resume' autoloading.
      static::$loading = false; // Reset for next time.

      // We now need to put the other callbacks back in.
      for($i = count($past) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
        spl_autoload_register($past[$i], true, true);

      if(class_exists($class_name))
        return true; // All is well
      throw new Exception('could not find class '.$class_name); // Not so well...
    } else {
      echo "Autoloader::autoload\n";
    }
  }
}

spl_autoload_register('a');
spl_autoload_register(Autoloader::$callback);
spl_autoload_register('b');

new Foo; // Would print `a, Autoloader::autoload, b` then the exception message.
```

One caveat with this is that callbacks occurring after `Autoloader::autoload` will happen twice, as the exception won't actually break out of the autoload chain.  Whilst it would be possible to remove these callbacks before raising the exception, that would break the autoload sequence if the exception was caught (e.g if `['a', 'Autoloader...', 'c']` was on the stack and the class was not found, either `c` will be executed twice as in the code above, or the code could be modified to make `c` happen once, but if the exception was caught the autoload stack would be left as `['a', 'Autoloader...']`).

Comment: One reason I chose to go the route of multiple autoloaders though was due to performance/speed. If one goes the route of only using a single autoload function and within that function parse/match the class name strings, there would be no problem with throwing the exception as you only have one include to contend with. The draw back of this approach is that you exert a lot of processing power for simply loading classes. With multiple autoloaders, there isn't much processing occurring as each autoloader is responsible for a specific segment of classes/paths.

Comment: You're right, of course.  I don't think it's something I would use in a production environment since, as you say, the overhead of finding each class is rather high.  This was more-or-less driven by the idea of ensuring the exception is only thrown if all callbacks fail (even ones that are added after `Autoloader`.  I may take another look at it later and see if I can improve it (was well past my bed-time when I posted it).